# Syntax difference between pointer to int array and pointer to int

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Let us consider the below code:

```
int y = 20;
int *pointer_of_y = y; //Intentionally missed &
printf("%p\n",pointer_of_y);
printf("%p\n",&y);
printf("%d\n",*pointer_of_y);
```

Output:

```
0x14 //Value of 20 in hex
0x7fff56747af8 //Address of Y Variable
Segmentation fault: 11 //Value at pointer: Due to missing &
```

The above code does not execute because I have missed & in pointer initialisation.

Let us consider the same code if it is initialised as array.

```
int x[]= {10,20,30,40};
int *pointer_of_x = x;
printf("%p\n",pointer_of_x);
printf("%p\n",&x);
printf("%d\n",*pointer_of_x);
```

The output :

```
0x7fff5b5eaad0  //Pointer value
0x7fff5b5eaad0  //Address of x
10 //Value at address pointed
```

How does the second example work even though I have missed the & in the pointer initialisation. Why does being a array make a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the name of an array is used in an expression context other than as the operand to `sizeof` or `&` it decays to a `pointer` to its first element.

So here -

```
int x[]= {10,20,30,40};
```

`x` will give address of first element of array and has type `int *`. 
Therefore this works -

```
int *pointer_of_x = x;   //works
```

Comment: I'd remove "*the name of*", as the name is not relevant in this context.

Comment: @alk I think it is relevant, but more accurate would be *the identifier of*

Comment: @FelixPalmen: In C names or identifiers are for the parser only. "*Expression evaluating to an array*" might do.

Comment: @alk so? doesn't matter at the syntax level, and that's what was asked.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: The question is not about syntax (syntax error: `int i = 1; int * pi := i;`). It is about semantics (semantical "error": `int i = 1; int * pi = i;`)

Answer (score 2):

If an array of type `T` is assigned to a pointer of type `T*` then the array decays to the address of its 1<sup>st</sup> element.